# Navbar with jQuery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to mimic a navbar that has a slidedown/fadein effect and slideup/fadeout effect. However, I'm getting stuck with the jQuery animations...:/ Any help well appreciated please. The navbar I'm going for is cited in the comment on jsfiddle because I don't know if I can put it here ¯_(ツ)_/¯

**UPDATE: GOT IT - TY #jQuery on freenode // had to edit again because was disappearing when my mouse was over the div with the test test test **

https://jsfiddle.net/106p6xvh/4/

```
$(function () {
  if (parseInt($(document).width) <= 990) {
    console.log('triggered');
    $('.js-navbar-collapse').removeClass('navbar-nav');
    $('.js-navbar-collapse').addClass('navbar-stacked');
  }

  $('.navbar-nav>li>a').mouseover(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-stack').
    css('opacity', 0)
      .slideDown('slow')
      .animate(
      { opacity: 1 },
      { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
    );
  });

  $('.nav-items').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).attr('id'));
  });

  $('.navbar-nav>li>a, .nav-items').mouseleave(function() {
    var stack_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (stack_id.indexOf('-stack') == -1) {
      stack_id += "-stack";
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($('#' + stack_id).is(":hover") == false) {
        $('#' + stack_id).slideUp(500).animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, {
          queue: true,
          duration: 'slow'
        });
      }
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by getting stuck? What is the actual problem?

Comment: its on the coments. http://www.anthropologie.com/anthro/index.jsp

Comment: Check out my animation, compared to their's. It's wonky, if I could do a timeout before the slideup animation I think I would be set. However, every time I put setTimeOut around it, it just times out indefinitely :/

Answer (score 0):

See what my edit above

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + stack_id).slideUp(500).animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 'slow'
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
```